# not able to compile...cannot find the file

Tags: errors, compiling, winedt

I can`t compile my codes in WinEdt.there is always the error: error launching console application PDFTeXify... the system cannot find the file specified.
this happens even on the simplest code. what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just in case: did you install WinEdt *after* your distribution?

Comment: If you use the command line to go to the directory of your file and type `pdflatex myfile`, what happens?